# What is fastest way to find data in SQL Server CE Winforms

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms, sql-server-ce

I changed my software database from MS Access to SQL Server CE. I can not use other databases because I don't have (Admin) permission on clients to install.

I have indexed several columns according to need. I am confused to find data in SQL Server CE, because there are several ways to do so. I can use `SqlCeResultSet`, `SqlCeDataReader` and other methods to find data.

Which one is used and WHEN it is used since `SqlCeResultSet` provides several `ResultSetOptions`. I have ID is primary key in table `Users` and 3 types of queries are generally used  :

Select several columns with where conditions:

```
SELECT Id, email, mobile
FROM Users
WHERE Users.Tmpid = 3
  AND connected = 1;
```

Select Several Fields with primary key:

```
SELECT email, mobile, address
FROM Users
WHERE Id = 10;
```

No where condition:

```
SELECT Max(TmpId)
FROM Users;
```

I am confused which one is used when. Which one provides the fastest way to find data in SQL Server CE?

Comment: @PaulF Yes i have read that. It was about SqlDataAdapter, i am confused between SqlCeResultSet and SqlCeDataReader. Could you please provide the Performance between these two. and when we should use SqlCeResultSet?

Comment: `SqlCeDataReader` allows you to process the data "as it is downloaded", while as far as I know `SqlCeResultSet` loads all records before you can access them. Btw, `SqlCeResultSet` inherits from `SqlCeDataReader`, so you're always using `SqlCeDataReader` :P

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Thanks for that - I was just going to say the same - if all records are read then performance should be similar.

Comment: Note that SQL CE is now (sadly) deprecated.https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/95797446-0f9d-4e75-9007-adcd6f6a9d1e/is-sql-server-compact-dead-?forum=sqlce

Answer (score 1):

You should use an index and then the TableDirect API, as in the sample code below, in my informal measurements, it was about 30 % faster.

```
public CacheElement FindElementByKey(Guid key)
{
  using (var command = _connection.CreateCommand())
  {
    command.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
    command.CommandText = "CacheElement";
    command.IndexName = "PK_CacheElement";

    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        reader.Seek(DbSeekOptions.FirstEqual, key);
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            var element = new CacheElement();
            element.Key = key;
            element.Tag = reader.GetValue(1) == DBNull.Value ? null : reader.GetString(1);
            element.Value = (byte[])reader.GetValue(2);
            element.CreatedAt = reader.GetDateTime(3);
            element.ExpirationAt = reader.GetDateTime(4);
            return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

See my blog post for a sample and more info: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2015/07/sql-server-compact-adonet-data-access.html